# How to allow marking only one image in the datatist?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datalist

How using jquery to style selected image in
image gallery based in datalist, so that when you select another picture in gallery, styles from the previous selected image is removed.
Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('.Image1').click(function () {
                $(this).css('border', '3px solid orange');
             });
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling a class is simpler to undo than using `css()` since you can easily target that class as a selector to remove it

```js
$('.Image1').click(function() {
  // remove class from prior selection
  $('.Image1.selected').removeClass('selected');
  // add classs to current selection
  $(this).addClass('selected')
});
```

```css
.Image1 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.Image1.selected {
  border: 3px solid orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Image1">One</div>
<div class="Image1">Two</div>
<div class="Image1">Three</div>
<div class="Image1">Four</div>
```